# Python Selenium click load more on table

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, python-webbrowser

I am trying to get the whole data of [this](https://www.kaggle.com/c/coleridgeinitiative-show-us-the-data/leaderboard) table. However, in the last row there is "Load More" table row that I do not know how to load. So far I have tried different approaches that did not work,

1. I tried to click on the row itself by this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', {"class": "competition-leaderboard__table"})

i = 0
for team in table.find.all('tbody'):
    rows = team.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        i = i + 1
        if (i == 51):
            row.click()

        //the scraping code for the first 50 elements
```

The code above throws an error saying that "'NoneType' object is not callable".

Another thing that I have tried that did not work is the following:
I tried to get the load more table row by its' class and click on it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

load_more = driver.find_element_by_class_name('competition-leaderboard__load-more-wrapper')
load_more.click()

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
```

The code above also did not work.

So my question is how can I make python click on the "Load More" table row as in the HTML structure of the [site](https://www.kaggle.com/c/coleridgeinitiative-show-us-the-data/leaderboard) it seems like "Load More" is not a button that is clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have to accept cookies first, and then you can click 'Load more' button.

CSS selectors are the most suitable in this case.

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get('https://www.kaggle.com/c/coleridgeinitiative-show-us-the-data/leaderboard')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".sc-pAyMl.dwWbEz .sc-AxiKw.kOAUSS>.sc-AxhCb.gsXzyw")))
cookies = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".sc-pAyMl.dwWbEz .sc-AxiKw.kOAUSS>.sc-AxhCb.gsXzyw").click()
load_more = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".competition-leaderboard__load-more-count").click()
time.sleep(10)  # Added for you to make sure that both buttons were clicked
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

I tested this snippet and it clicked the desired button.
Note that I've added `WebDriverWait` in order to wait until the first button is clickable.

**UPDATE:**
I added time.sleep(10) so you could see that both buttons are clicked.

Comment: I tried to use your solution with my code and it does not seem to work, could you please take a look.

Comment: I think there is an issue with the CSS selector part of the code. Could you please explain how they work as there are multiple components nested in one another?

Comment: `.` is placed before class name, `>` is for direct child. Use `.class1.class2` when you need to input two classes names in one selector  `.class1>.class2` : class2 is a direct child of a class 1.

Comment: I have tested it and it worked, I'll check a little later again.