# Getting the XPath of elements

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, python-webbrowser

When you first enter [this](https://www.kaggle.com/c/coleridgeinitiative-show-us-the-data/leaderboard) site on the bottom of the site there is a statement that the site is using cookies. (You can use private window to get the "cookie statement" every time) I would like to get the XPath for the "Got it" button that basically accepts cookies.
The next thing that I am struggling with is the XPath for the "Load More" button at the end of the table.

P.S.
I need these XPaths for my other question which is partly answered. You can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67383440/python-selenium-click-load-more-on-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Got it` element `xpath` is `(//div[contains(text(),'Got it')])[2]`
The second element `xpath` is `//span[@class='competition-leaderboard__load-more-count']`